# Dynamic update of arcpy.AddMessage progress line in dialog box?

Tags: arcpy, update, progress, dialog

I have a lengthy field list and would like the dialog box to show script progress on a single line, rather than returning to a new line.

what I have:

field1

field2

field3
....

current code:

```
for fieldName in fieldList.split(';'):
    arcpy.gp.CalculateField_management(inFeature, fieldName, "2")
    arcpy.gp.AddMessage(fieldName)
```

what I would like:

field1, field2, field3, ...

 I don't want to simply list the fields, but keep the list updating with a new field separated by a comma each time on the same line

Comment: Are you talking about background or foreground Geoprocessing?  Have you looked into SetProgessor? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/setprogressor.htm

Comment: Foreground processing. I did see SetProgressor but I was hoping to use AddMessage (or something else) to see updates in the dialog box.

Comment: While I think this can be done with a `print` statement, I don't believe it can be done using `arcpy.AddMessage()`

Comment: @bleegp the SetProgressor will allow you to display text

Comment: you can display tex with SetProgressorLabel:  arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Loading {0}...".format(shp))

Comment: @ShiuliPervin Perhaps, with the addition of a quick code snippet that demonstrates what you are suggesting, you can write your comment up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**This is How you will use SetProgressor:**

You can try this progress bar functions. May be you need a little modification according to your python versions. So, I donot know that dialog box is possible in arcgis custom tool box. But you can see the progresses in progressbar labels as you expected I hope.

```
count=1
arcpy.SetProgressor("step","Calculating fields for fieldnew Values", 0, len(fieldList),1)
    field_names=["..."]
    for fieldName in fieldList.split(';'):
        field_name.insert[count-1, fieldName] 
        arcpy.SetProgressorLabel(" Calculating field :{}".format(fieldName))
        arcpy.gp.CalculateField_management(inFeature, fieldName, "2")
        arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("We are done with {}".format(field_names))
        #arcpy.gp.AddMessage(fieldName)

    count=count+1
```